# Internet connectivity issue when setting up static ip address in raspberry pi

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, raspberry-pi, static-ip

I have program running on my raspberry pi3 to set up a static ip configuration based on the ip address range of the router to which it is connected. But when I connect the pi to a router with 10.0.x.x range IP, the device is getting a static IP address but it could not connect to internet. My configurations in dhcpcd.conf file are listed below

interface eth0

inform 10.0.0.x

static routers=10.0.0.1

static domain_name_servers=208.67.222.222

---

But these configurations works fine with 192.168 range routers

interface eth0

inform 192.168.0.x

static routers=192.168.0.1

static domain_name_servers=208.67.222.222

---

After a little retries I found that if I remove the "static routes.." line from the dhcpcd.conf file, the pi could connect to internet in the 10.0 range routers. But when connected to the 192.168 range routers it will not connect to internet without specifying "static router.."

Please help me how to fix this issue. Thanks in andvance.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. Are you trying to make your Pi auto configure itself on a static IP no matter what network it is connected to? Or, are you just moving it between a couple of networks that you know the settings for and are just making it switch back and forth the configs? How are you assuming the gateway is at 192.168.0.1 or 10.0.0.1? How do you know there isn't an IP conflict with another device on that network? How do you know the DNS server you specified is usable from both networks? There are a lot of missing details here as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Appleoddity I'm trying to make the pi auto configure a static ip itself. It request a dynamic IP for the first time and find the gateway address from it. Then configure a static ip settings as per that gateway. For the time being I am not considering ip address conflict